# Raising UserControl's default Click event

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, visual-studio-2017

I've created a usercontrol.
I've placed a Button into it.
Now when I click the button, I would like to raise the default Click event.

For that, I added the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RaiseEvent Click(sender, e)
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong here?

This is the entire code of the usercontrol:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ucColorButton

    <Browsable(True)>
    Public Overrides Property BackColor() As Color
        Get
            Return Me.Button1.BackColor
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            Me.Button1.BackColor = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RaiseEvent Click(sender, e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The compiler tells me:

```
There's no RaiseEvent definition for the event "Click"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `RaiseEvent` to raise an inherited event.  This is why all events should have an associated method.  To raise the `Click` event you call the `OnClick` method and that is the only place that `RaiseEvent` is used.  If you want to change the behaviour on a `Click` event then you override that method, otherwise you just accept the default behaviour from the base class.  To see how events are properly implemented - and are implemented in the base classes you're inheriting - [check this out](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html).

Also, while it technically doesn't matter in this case, you shouldn't really be passing the `e` parameter from your internal event handler to your external event.  You should be creating your own `EventArgs` object as required by your event.

Finally, if you were to be able to use `RaiseEvent`, it would be wrong to pass on the `sender` parameter too.  The `sender` is ALWAYS supposed to be the object that raised the event.  In your case, that is the user control, NOT the internal `Button`.  Fortunately, calling `OnClick` will fix that.  If you needed to pass on information about which child control was clicked then you should be defining your own event and passing that information via the `e` parameter.